# In ansys workbench, unable to apply bearing load

Tags: ansys

I'm using Ansys workbench 15 and new to it. I want to perform ball bearing stress analysis but I'm unable to apply bearing load to it. The problem is when I select faces and click on apply, it again shows no selection.

Can any body tell me what is the problem and how to perform ball bearing analysis.

Boundary conditions:

1. No separation type contact between grooves and bearings ball (grooves of both inner and outer races.)
2. Fixed support to outer race.

Fig. is attached showing contacts.[image][image]

Part 1 indicates groove of inner race and part 10 indicate grooves of outer race.

contact body - grooves

target body - balls

I want to apply radial load on bearing using bearing load at the center of inner race. My load is nearly 3000 N with rotational speed of 30 rad/sec.
I used Solidworks software to create my 3D model and then save it as .igs file and import it into Ansys.

Comment: Just out of interest try saving the model as .STP and try again...Soemtimes works for circular/cylindrical geometry (I'm unsure why!)